# Looping through pandas rows

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pandas

**Problem**

I have a of coordinates that I'm trying to decrease the number of rows based on long/lat precision.

```
             X          Y
0  -122.425892  37.774599
1  -122.425892  37.774599
2  -122.424363  37.800414
3  -122.426995  37.800873
4  -122.438738  37.771541
```

As you see the number of decimal points goes up to 6 points. The data that I have is about 800k rows. So I created a for loop to see how many rows are removed as I increase/decrease the number of decimal points

**Solution Attempt**

```
tr_df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=['X', 'Y'])

for i in list(range(0,7)):
    df = tr_df
    df.iloc[:,1:] = np.round(df.iloc[:,1:], decimals=i)
    df = df.drop_duplicates(['X','Y'])
    print(df.shape)
```

Doing so prints `(1, 3)` 6 times, which is incorrect. I put a `print(df.shape)` between every line and it always goes to `(1, 3)` after `drop_duplicates()` after resetting properly at the top of the loop `df=tr_df`.

**Question**

Where is the issue lying at? If I run the script by manually increasing the `decimals` I get correct output which is (for actual data):

```
(4, 3)
(138, 3)
(8858, 3)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple issues here. Firstly, you're not resetting anything with `df = tr_df`, you're just referencing the same object. If you need to make a copy, use `df = tr_df.copy()`.

Secondly, with `df.iloc[:,1:] = np.round(df.iloc[:,1:], decimals=i)` you're just rounding the Y column. After that, you select the subset `['X','Y']` for dropping columns, but because the X column hasn't been rounded, there's no duplicate rows!

I don't know how you "manually" got the right answer, but maybe this is what you're looking for (I added a helpful print statement):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tr_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['X', 'Y'])

for i in range(0,7):
    df = np.round(tr_df, decimals=i)
    df = df.drop_duplicates()
    print df
    print(df.shape)
```

Output:

```
     X   Y
0 -122  38
(1, 2)
       X     Y
0 -122.4  37.8
(1, 2)
        X      Y
0 -122.43  37.77
2 -122.42  37.80
3 -122.43  37.80
4 -122.44  37.77
(4, 2)
         X       Y
0 -122.426  37.775
2 -122.424  37.800
3 -122.427  37.801
4 -122.439  37.772
(4, 2)
          X        Y
0 -122.4259  37.7746
2 -122.4244  37.8004
3 -122.4270  37.8009
4 -122.4387  37.7715
(4, 2)
           X         Y
0 -122.42589  37.77460
2 -122.42436  37.80041
3 -122.42700  37.80087
4 -122.43874  37.77154
(4, 2)
            X          Y
0 -122.425892  37.774599
2 -122.424363  37.800414
3 -122.426995  37.800873
4 -122.438738  37.771541
(4, 2)
```

Comment: `tr_df.copy()` or `df = np.round(tr_df, decimals=i)` do the trick. Thanks. The reason this `np.round(df.iloc[:,1:], decimals=i)` worked is because in my actual data I had three columns where `[:,1:]` meant `['X','Y']`. I removed as much bogus info for the question but I have missed that. If you look at the `df.shape` in my question I have there's 3 columns.

Comment: OK, I was a bit confused about that, but I didn't mind it. Glad to help! Just be careful when compacting your questions.